How to find the intersections of two polynomial curves?
This question is derived from this one: How to solve the method of Lagrange multipliers? .
I want to know methods to find intersection points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of two plain curves defined as the set of zeros of polynomials $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$.
My attempt:

Draw a graph of each curve using some software.
Find intersections visually.

Is there a better (speed, precision) way than this primitive method?

Not faster but, for this kind of problems I use to make a contour plot of $f^2(x,y)+g^2(x,y)$ and try to see where is (are) the minima.

The key word you are looking for is elimination theory. Maybe the most cincrete is resultants
